# office-ui-fabric-react: How to change a theme's default font to be smaller

Tags: office-ui-fabric

The default font is a bit large for my target application.

I saw that loadTheme could change the primary theme color, but is there a way to change the default font size across all components?

IFontStyles has a variety of sizes specified, so is there a way to set the  font size for all the fabric react components to "small" (FontSizes.small)?

I have tried to set the css font-size to something smaller directly in the outer containers and inside the Fabric component, but the components still seem to render around 14px (ms-font-size-m) once rendering goes inside the Fabric component.

The theme code is fairly confusing to me but it looks like fabric-react uses a combination of fabric-core scss, fabric-react scss and glamor (runtime js->css) to generate stylesheets as needed and return the classnames to react code for className property. There does not appear to be use of inline styles.

Answer (score -1):

*loadTheme* can override font-szie.

Comment: Please provide an example.

Comment: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/master/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/Theme/docs/ThemesOverview.md